How do you establish a nested VPN tunnel using Strongswan?
I have four Ubuntu hosts: two "inner" (B/C) and two "outer" (A/D):
A --> B --> (INTERNET) <-- C <-- D

I can already successfully establish an IPSec connection between B & C. However what I want to achieve is a nested IPSec tunnel between A & D such that the tunnel is established and persisted through the B/C tunnel.
I have a fledgling understanding of the swanctl.conf options, so am not sure how to correctly implement this.
Ultimately, initiator traffic from A to receiver D must be routed through the B/C tunnel, however it appears that this routing is ultimately established by the Strongswan configuration.
My base initiator & receiver (B & C) configs:
# Initiator B
connections {
        inner_tunnel {
                remote_addrs = <server C public IP>

                version = 2
                proposals = aes256-sha512-x25519

                ppk_required = yes
                ppk_id = a2v-SoId7WN5Q19wptdaRWJp11EjPr1yYGWh8xlY62Q=

                children {
                        inner_tunnel {
                                local_ts = 192.168.108.103/24
                                remote_ts = 10.54.0.25/24
                                esp_proposals = aes256gcm12-x25519
                        }
                }

                local {
                        auth = psk
                }

                remote {
                        auth = psk
                }
        }
}


# Receiver C
connections {
        inner_tunnel {
                remote_addrs = %any
                pools = default_pool

                version = 2
                proposals = aes256-sha512-x25519

                ppk_required = yes

                children {
                        inner_tunnel {
                                remote_ts = 192.168.108.103/24
                                local_ts = 10.54.0.25/24
                                esp_proposals = aes256gcm12-x25519
                        }

                }

                local {
                        auth = psk
                        id = inner_hub
                }

                remote {
                        auth = psk
                }
        }
}

pools {
        default_pool {
                addrs = 10.1.30.0/24
        }
}


Just don't: establish theh nested one directly. Furthermore, if you have a setup where you should use a VPN inside a private network then something is rotten in the state of Denmark.
